# Can I add a new auto-increment column to this UNION?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I’m trying to join two tables getting all the data from both tables.

I managed to UNION both tables, but I need to add an ID with auto-increment as the primary key for the new table that I’m creating. 
I don't know how to do it and can’t find a way to add it to the query.

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE
SELECT T1.TEXT as TEXT
       [...]
       FROM TABLE1 T1
       LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
            on T1.TEXT = T2.TEXT
UNION
SELECT T2.TEXT as TEXT
       FROM TABLE1 T1
       [...]
       RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 T2
            on T1.TEXT = T2.TEXT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the column definitions in the `CREATE TABLE` statement to add the `id` column. Then provide `NULL` as the values for it in the `SELECT` queries.

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text TEXT,
    [...]
) AS
SELECT null, T1.TEXT
       [...]
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
    on T1.TEXT = T2.TEXT
UNION
SELECT null, T2.TEXT as TEXT
FROM TABLE1 T1
[...]
RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 T2
    on T1.TEXT = T2.TEXT
```